# ACF - Getting Values and Labels Of A Sub Field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a Radio Button inside a Repeater Field,
to create two selects filters in this page http://artistresidencebrighton.co.uk/neighbourhood/
As you can see opening one of the select, I am getting the same option repeated x times.

What I’d like to get is only one instance of the option regardless how many squares have that class in the page.

I was wondering if there is a simple and clean solution for this issue.

Below the code responsible to output the selects and their option fields

```
<div class="block-filter block-filter--area btn-skin u-cf"><!-- Area -->
<label class="block-filter__label u-textCapitalize u-block u-textLeft" for="area">area</label>
<span class="block-filter__select-wrapper" id="area">
  <select id="select--areas">
    <option value="all--areas">All</option>
    <?php if( get_field('neighbourhood') ): ?>
      <?php 
      $neighbourhood_areas = array();
      while( has_sub_field('neighbourhood') ): 

        $area  = get_sub_field_object('neighbourhood_area');
        $area_value  = get_sub_field('neighbourhood_area');
        $area_label  = $area['choices'][$area_value];
      ?>

        <?php if( !in_array($area_value, $neighbourhood_areas) ): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $area_value; ?>"><?php echo $area_label; ?></option>
        <?php $neighbourhood_areas[] = $area_value; endif; ?>  

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </select>
</span>
</div>


<div class="block-filter block-filter--type btn-skin u-cf"><!-- Type -->
<label class="block-filter__label u-textCapitalize u-block u-textLeft" for="type">type</label>
<span class="block-filter__select-wrapper" id="type">
  <select id="select--types">
    <option value="all--types">All</option>
    <?php if( get_field('neighbourhood') ): ?>
      <?php 
      $neighbourhood_types = array();
      while( has_sub_field('neighbourhood') ): 

        $type  = get_sub_field_object('neighbourhood_type');
        $type_value  = get_sub_field('neighbourhood_type');
        $type_label  = $type['choices'][$type_value];
      ?>

        <?php if( !in_array($type_value, $neighbourhood_types) ): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $type_value; ?>"><?php echo $type_label; ?></option>
        <?php $neighbourhood_types[] = $type_value; endif; ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </select>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a `DISTICT` in your query. I am not familiar with `acf`, so a hack to do the same thing is to create an array, and if it is not in the array, than print, ie -> `<?php $neighbourhood_types=array(); while( has_sub_field('neighbourhood') ): $type  = ...; $type_value  = ...; $type_label  = ...; if(!in_array($type_value, $neighbourhood_types) { //if not in array, print and add to array $neighbourhood_type[]=$type_value; ?> <option value="<?php echo $type_value; ?>">...</option><?php } endwhile; ?>`

Comment: @Sean Thanks I've tried using your solution in localhost but nothing seems to happend! Have a look if you find any error in the code (only the second select)

Comment: You never added the value to the array -> `$neighbourhood_types[] = $type_value;`. Add this inside your `if/endif`, ie. -> `<?php if( !in_array($type_value, $neighbourhood_types) ): ?> ... <?php $neighbourhood_types[] = $type_value; endif; ?>`

Comment: Now you have your `<option value="<?php echo $type_value; ?>"><?php echo $type_label; ?></option>` outside the `if/elseif`. That needs to stay inside the `if/elseif` so that it is only printed if not in the array. In my last comment I abbreviated it to `...` so as not to have to retype, but it looks like you misunderstood. You need `<?php if( !in_array($type_value, $neighbourhood_types) ): ?><option value="<?php echo $type_value; ?>"><?php echo $type_label; ?></option><?php $neighbourhood_types[] = $type_value; endif; ?>`

Comment: @Sean It works! Thanks. I will apply to the other select too

Comment: Glad to help. Now you can do the same thing on your `neighbourhood_area` select.

Comment: @Sean DONE http://artistresidencebrighton.co.uk/neighbourhood/ There is a chance to optimize the code? or for you it is already perfect?

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer to the question, not as an edit to the question. I've rolled it back for now, but you can get rep and badges for sharing what you learned with future readers.